# I have a process which I believe may be getting preempted. How can I find out what is interfering with it?

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, scheduling, interrupt

A small c++ program that does nothing but the following:

```
struct bat
{
    const char* a;
    const char* b;
    void*       v;
};

struct rat
{
    rat()
        : 
          isOn(true),
          bats(),
          batscounter(0) {}

    uint64_t
    update()
        {
            uint64_t start = rdtsc();
            if (!isOn)
                return;

            bat& b = bats[batscounter];
            batscounter = (++batscounter % 10);
            b.v = this;
            b.a = "aname";
            b.b = "bname";
            return (rdtsc() - start);
        }

    bool isOn;
    bat bats[10];
    size_t batscounter;
};
```

Looping over it and inspecting the timestamps from rdtsc I see an average of 20 cycles but a lot of the time I see spikes over 20K cycles (every second). The method is getting called about 70M times per second. I am running this on an empty host using `ulimit -r 99` and I even set the affinity mask for the process to `1` to see if that would help but it hasn't. What could be causing this with those settings on and what other methods would I have available to me to prevent this?

Comment: Possible thread related: use real time priority: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887531/which-real-time-priority-is-the-highest-priority-in-linux

Comment: I have only a main thread though and ulimit -r 99 sets the real time priority though doesn't it?

Comment: My `ulimit` has no `-r` switch, so I have no idea at all what that's supposed to do.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? See the linked question, apparently it's 1 the higher limit.

Comment: No, it's 99...the priority is inverted with ulimit and 99 is higher..if you set ulimit -r 80 and then try to set ulimit r 90 it wont allow you.

Comment: I noticed no difference in these rare preemptions even when i used set_sched to get priority up to 139 (99 real time priority) There are still a ton of watchdog and migration daemons at that same priority level though.